# How to Align text right below an image?

Tags: html, css, image, web, flexbox

I've created a flex based image gallery that i have aligned onto the center off my web page, it looks good so far but i'm stuck on how to align text right underneath each individual image. I want the text to be a header, and a small paragraph that aligns with the corresponding image on-top off it. I've been hard stuck on how to accomplish this.

here is what im trying to accomplish [image: Trying to replicate]

here is my code: `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
* {
   margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight:400;
  letter-spacing:3px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  overflow:hidden;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color:black;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  padding:10px;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 26px;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
/*
h1 {
 Come check on this later
 need to start giving all my h1's and h2's seperate classes
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  top:40%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index:-1;
}
*/
h2{
  text-align:center;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align:center;
}
.wrapper p {
  text-align:justify;
}
.buttstyle {
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: white;
      border:solid black;
      width: 250px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      letter-spacing:1px;
}
.buttstyle:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.item{
  margin:20px;
  border:solid black;
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  #navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .nav-links {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  .logo {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  
  .nav-links:hover {
    background-color: white;
        color: black;
  }

  .background {
  background-image: url("https://zululandobserver.co.za/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/11/Construction.jpg");
   background-position: center top;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
   width:100%;
  height:500px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.backgroundfoot{
  background-image: url("https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/5755a35501dbae3c6d1ba03e/1466431188847-3AV4M2XMF3RADSVDN4O3/black-and-white-restaurant-eating-sitting.jpg?content-type=image%2Fjpeg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
  position:relative;
}
.backgroundfoot h1{
  left: 0px;
  width:40px;
  color:red;
}

.wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1200px;
      /* Not sure if i want to keep this styling in the future*/
      text-align:initial;
      }
.header
        {
  top: 0px;
  position:absolute; 
  color:blue;
}
.backgroundfoot .flexcontainer {
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
}
h1 {
  color:black;
}
#mingallery {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
.item {
  border:none;
  margin:20px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}

}
 
 

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <header>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">Lipsum</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div style="height: 72px;"></div>
  </header>
  <section>
    <div class =' '>
      <div class ='background'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class = 'wrapper'>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>
      <br>
      <a href='AboutUs.html'><button type="button" class ='buttstyle'>Find out More About US</button></a>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class = 'wrapper'>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>
    </div>
    <br>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Our Services</h1>
    <div id = 'mingallery'>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/210881/pexels-photo-210881.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" class = 'item' alt="Girl in a jacket" width="400" height="250">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/210881/pexels-photo-210881.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" class = 'item' alt="Girl in a jacket" width="400" height="250">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/210881/pexels-photo-210881.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" class = 'item' alt="Girl in a jacket" width="400" height="250">

      </div>
  </section>
  <footer>
<div class='backgroundfoot'>
  <div class ='flexcontainer'>
<h1>Join the construction team</h1>
  </footer>
</body>
  <script>
let mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu");
let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle");

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle("active");
});
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

  </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place each image, text, and button, all in the same parent element, then place the parents in a flexbox. This will group them all together and cause them to layout together.

I have created a small example.

Also, in future questions, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then in stead of looking through your whole webpage, we can just look at the important part.

```css
#mingallery {
   display:flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}

#mingallery .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:none;
  margin:20px;
}

#mingallery .item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#mingallery .item h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;">Our Services</h1>
  <div id = 'mingallery'>
    <div class = 'item'>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/210881/pexels-photo-210881.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" alt="Girl in a jacket">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
      <p>Image Text</p>
      <button>Image Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class = 'item'>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/210881/pexels-photo-210881.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" alt="Girl in a jacket">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
      <p>Image Text</p>
      <button>Image Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class = 'item'>
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/210881/pexels-photo-210881.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=650&w=940" alt="Girl in a jacket">
      <h2>Image Title</h2>
      <p>Image Text</p>
      <button>Image Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e0/ba/ff/e0baff6beabb273243f9f17a092f6709.gif">
<h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
```